# Is there a Visual Studio extension that shows which methods do not have XML documentation?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I'm looking for a way to find the methods in a large solution that do not have XML documentation. Without trawling class by class, project by project through the solution, is there a simple way?

(Ideally I'd like to be able to double-click to navigate straight to the offending method)

Comment: I know when I use Sandcastle to build my help file from the code, it issues warnings for all elements that are missing the XML.

Comment: @Moo-Juice thanks for the heads-up. Will investigate...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a built-in way in Visual Studio. In your project Properties -> Build page, tick the XML documentation file box, and rebuild. All methods without XML documentation generate a warning.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for - the perfect solution. And being warnings, you can double-click 'em too, of course! Thanks for your answer.

Comment: No probs, glad I could help.

Comment: Just got to go through the 1988 warnings and I'll be all set (for Christmas). Thanks!

Comment: Yikes...by the way, have you tried GhostDoc? Automatically gets you started on adding XML headers for methods. I use it all the time, might speed things up a bit for you.

Comment: Yeh, I use GhostDoc - it's great. Will definitely help!